# Notificación de Firebase Cloud Messaging no llega con la app cerrada

Tags: java, android, android-studio

estoy intentando recibir un mensaje desde Cloud Messaging y no me llega con la app cerrada, si la app está en segundo plano si llega.

FirebaseS.java

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;


public class FirebaseS extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        if (remoteMessage.getData().isEmpty())
            notmanager(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        else
            notmanager(remoteMessage.getData());

    }

    private void notmanager(Map<String, String> data) {
        String title = data.get("title");
        String body = data.get("body");
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "WH.FCM";
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "Notification",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationChannel.setDescription("");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

        }
        NotificationCompat.Builder notb = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        notb.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.chanel_ic)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body);
        notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(),notb.build());
    }

    private void notmanager(String title, String body) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "WH.FCM";
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "Notification",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationChannel.setDescription("");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

        }
        NotificationCompat.Builder notb = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        notb.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.chanel_ic)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body);
        notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(),notb.build());
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
        <service
            android:name=".FirebaseS">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

**EDITO:**
Lo solucioné cambiando el código, lo único que no pude hacer que funcione es que muestre una imagen enviada desde FCM, por lo demás lo arregle, comparto el código por si alguien tiene el mismo problema.
También me sirvió el comentario de jorgesys sobre la batería, ya que en la primera build era el problema de la batería.

```
  public Bitmap bitmap;
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // ...
        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            handleNow(remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            notmanager(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }


        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    }
    private void handleNow(Map<String, String> data) {
        String title = data.get("title");
        String body = data.get("body");
        String imageUri = data.get("image");
        bitmap = getBitmapfromUrl(imageUri);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "WH.FCM";
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "Notification",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationChannel.setDescription("");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

        }
        NotificationCompat.Builder notb = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        notb.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.chanel_ic)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body);
        notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(),notb.build());
    }
    private void notmanager(String title, String body) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "WH.FCM";
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "Notification",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationChannel.setDescription("");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

        }
        NotificationCompat.Builder notb = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        notb.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.chanel_ic)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body);
        notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(),notb.build());
    }
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);

        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // Instance ID token to your app server.
        //sendRegistrationToServer(token);
    }
    public Bitmap getBitmapfromUrl(String imageUrl) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return bitmap;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Algo se muestra en el LogCat, has revisado ?

Comment: Cuando la app está en segundo plano llega y cuando está "muerta" en el log me muestra body: test en rojo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noto que recibes y procesas la notificaciòn (el payload) dentro del mètodo `onMessageReceived()` lo cual es correcto

```
   public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        if (remoteMessage.getData().isEmpty())
            notmanager(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        else
            notmanager(remoteMessage.getData());

    }
```

Deberìas de recibir la notificaciòn pero si el sistema operativo en el cual presentas el problema es 8 o posterior, debes asegurar que no se encuentre activada la optimizaciòn de la baterìa, esto podrìa ser el principal problema.

Ve a Configuracion - Baterìa - Optimizaciòn de baterìa -  busca la aplicaciòn y deshabilita la optimizaciòn.

Comment: Estoy probando en un android 10, aunque también leí que en android 5 pasaba algo similar.

Comment: Revisa por favor si no tienes activada la optimización de la batería.

Comment: En mi android 10 desactive la optimización y sigue sin llegar los mensajes con la app cerrada, ahora en un android con api 27 funciona de maravilla

Comment: En android 10 has depurado para saber si se recibe el payload dentro de onMessageReceived( ) @Max  ?

Comment: eh, como depuro?

Comment: Bueno estando cerrada tal vez no puedas, pero que te parece si agregas Logs para imprimir que obtienes como payload o revisar el LogCat para ver si cuando recibe la notificación se provoca un error.

Comment: ¿como uso ``Log.e();`` para imprimir eso?